# Firefox fixed element lost width

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with fixed element width in Firefox. Element is search bar. Under search bar is a scrollable part of page. Search bar was scrolling with the rest of the page so I added class with position fixed. Now search bar is fixed and the rest of the page is scrolling under the bar. In Chrome and Opera everything works fine but in Firefox search bar lost it's width. Why?

[image: Search bar fixed working - image]
[image: Search bar fixed Firefox - image]

Comment: post your code here , or add your code in fiddle,

Comment: Just add to fixed element `width: 100%;`

Comment: Pls post some code